# How to shift the histogram of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to change the brightness of a gray-scale image with histogram shifting. So, I need to set the lower boundary as 25 and upper boundary as 225 and then shift the histogram by +50. How can I do that?

I tried `imcontrast` but it's not exactly histogram shifting.

After applying this transformation, the gray-scale image should be a bit brighter since it's shifted by +50 (i.e. if a pixel's gray-scale value is 75, it will become 125 after transformation. Pixels with values like 20 or 250 will not be included since the lower boundary is 25 and the upper boundary is 225.)

```
flower = imread('FlowerN.jpg');
gray = rgb2gray(flower);
for i=1:length(gray)
    i>25 AND i<225
    i = i+50
end
```

Comment: You forgot to add your code. Please read the [tour].

Comment: I do not think that this will be possible with Histogram, the way you are expecting. Histogram gives you the no of pixels in image with certain values. It will not precisely give you its location. On the first glance this problem does not seem to have a solution using histograms. I don't exactly know if it does. I will be glad (and curious) to know if you make this through (fingers-crossed).

Comment: You just select the pixels with specific value and change their value. Its not only possible, but easy. `Img(Img==25)=25+50` for one specific value, for example.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Is this the histogram shifiting Poster asked for?

Comment: OP asked a vague question, so no this is not the full answer. But shifting the entire histogram by 50 is easier than this, its just adding 50 to the image. Nothing else. My point is that you say that this is impossible, which is not.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I was referring to the same. I saw [this post](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/442002-image-transfromation-histogram-shifting) while looking for an answer to this. *(I have not used matlab since last 2 years so I had to research)*. My point was simply to point that **getting histogram  > shifting by 50 > reconstructing Image** would be next level of coding. Surely there will be ways to do it better (like the one you suggested)

Comment: Your post however is not a good answer to the question, even if the question is bad, and I  think should be removed.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ohh It's all good. I understand I should have commented rather than Answering. "learnt new tips"

Comment: No worries ;) Thats how we all learn

Comment: `i>25 AND i<225` is not valid MATLAB syntax. Surely this gave you an error, right?

Comment: Your code snippet has many errors. You want to use `numel(gray)` to iterate over all pixels, not `length`, which is the longest side of the image. `AND` is not valid MATLAB, but this statement is also missing an `if`. Finally, your loop does not address `gray` at all, you are changing `i` which is not saved anywhere. I suggest you read some of these [fantastic MATLAB tutorials](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html), it will make learning MATLAB a lot easier than the trial and error process you're doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shift the image's histogram, you should change all pixel values by the same amount:

```
gray = gray + 50;
```

If `gray` is of type `uint8`, this addition will use saturated arithmetic, meaning that any result over 255 will be capped at 255. That is, `uint8(240) + 50 == uint8(255)`.

Comment: what does "uint8(240)" mean? Also, how can I make it be capped at 225? Any result lower than 25 should be 25 as well.

Comment: @SanghyeonYi: You can type that command in MATLAB, you'll see what it means. It casts the number 240 to 8-bit unsigned integer (numbers are always double-float values unless you cast them). What is the reason you want to cap values at 225? Then you're no longer just shifting the histogram. `max(min(gray,225),25)` will cap values below 25 and above 225.